# Can't use keys of less that 64 bits long

Tags: warning-messages, cryptography

Probably a bug:

```
key = GenerateSymmetricKey[
      Method -> <|"Cipher" -> "Blowfish", "KeySize" -> 16|>]
Encrypt[key, "test"]
```

**`Encrypt::invkeyspec: Key should a string or valid SymmetricKey, PrivateKey, or PublicKey.`**

Even though the documentation says:

- The following ciphers can use any key size that is a multiple of 8:

  ```
  "RC4"
  "Blowfish"
  "CAST5"
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the documentation is misleading. According to Wikipedia, Blowfish keys should be between 32 and 448 bits. For some reason, `Encrypt` insists a Blowfish key be a multiple of 64, and will accept any such key, even ones larger than 448 (7 x 64).

```
BlowfishTest[k_, msg_String] :=
  Module[{key}, 
   key = GenerateSymmetricKey[Method -> <|"Cipher" -> "Blowfish", "KeySize" -> k 64|>]; 
  Decrypt[key, Encrypt[key, msg]]]
```

The following tests all keys that are multiples of 64 up 1024 (16 x 64).

```
With[{msg = "This is a test."}, 
  AllTrue[Table[BlowfishTest[k, msg], {k, 16}], # == msg &]]
```

> `True`